# Freemarker: how to use Multimap (or Map of Lists)

Tags: java, freemarker, multimap

I'm trying to use a **com.google.common.collect.Multimap<String, Foo>** from Freemarker.

In a Multimap, for each key in the map, you get back Collection.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

Java:

```
context.put("itemsByCategory", itemsByCategory);
```

FreeMarker:

```
<#list exclusiveItems?keys as cat>
    ${cat}<br/>
    <#assign items = exclusiveItems[cat]>
    <#list items as item>
        ${item.id}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

I got the following exception. It appears it's treating Items as a scalar, although it's actually a Collection.

```
?size is unsupported for: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> list items as item [on line 61, column 49 in email/foo/foo-html.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: ?size is unsupportefor:freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
```

Comment: Is either the context name or the FM template var name incorrect in the snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

Instead of passing in a Multimap instance ("itemsByCategory"), as in the example, I found that transforming the Multimap to a raw Map> and then using that works with the FreeMarker snippet above unchanged.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Congrats on the solution! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success. Cheers~

Comment: Note that that's like so because `MultiMap` isn't a `java.util.Map`. So FreeMarker doesn't recognize it as something that has map-like functionality. However, one could create a custom `ObjectWrapper` that does that.

Answer (score 1):

You say it treats the value as a scalar, but it seems it treats it as a method. What if you just list the keys? Aren't there some method names among them? Because then your problem is most certainly that you haven't set the `simpleMapWrapper` JavaBean property of the `BeansWrapper` that you are using to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `keySet` and `asMap`.

The `keys` method will give a collection of keys that may (probably will) contain duplicates. This gives back a key for each value, even if the key is used twice. `keySet` gives a list of unique keys.